# How to cache Exchange web service API autodiscoverurl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, exchangewebservices

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659837%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

According to link above, we can caching the information for Autodiscover.

The question is:

1) Should i serialize ExchangeService object to xml or just cache some of the properties (which properties) ? (I want to improve performance of the system because autodiscoverurl is too slow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you cache the minimum information your app needs to function.

[This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn528374(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_CacheSettings) suggests

- Autodiscover endpoint
- EWS URL and any other settings retrieved from the Autodiscover response

Comment: let's say i just cache the EWS URL, how should i verify again whether the url is still valid or not ?

Comment: I think you would: get the URL and cache it. Use the URL for the next 24 hours. If within that you get an error then go and get it again. If you don't the only go and get it if the 24 hours is up.

Answer (score 0):

Most apps just cache the EWS URL.  If you are requesting any additional properties when making [GetUserSettings operation (SOAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877096(v=exchg.150).aspx), you could cache them as well.  And please make AutoDiscover request at least once every 24 hours.  I am not sure it would help to serialize ExchangeService, or if it is even possible to serialize this.